# Is there a good way to iterate 2 lists with different length continuously?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists.

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And I want to print them in this way

```
(1, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(3, 'c')
(4, 'a')
(5, 'b')
(1, 'a')
(2, 'b')
# ... and so on ...
```

Is there a clean way to do it?

Comment: You can probably look at `zip` and `cycle` from `itertools`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap both of your lists with `itertools.cycle`, then pass them to `zip` to iterate simultaneously and build 2-tuples with one value from each:

```
import itertools

for tup in zip(itertools.cycle(a), itertools.cycle(b)):
    print(tup) # or whatever you want to do with the tuples
```

Note, this loop will run forever, so you'll probably want some other code in there to eventually `break` out of it.